# Preg_match_all behaving wierd

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I am new to PHP and I have the below code and I basically wish to find all keywords enclosed between

> '<#' and  '#>'

sample code:

```
<?php

$subject = "askdbvbaldjbvasdblasdbvl<#2134#>cbkdbskbkabdvb<#213aca4#>";
$pattern = "/(?<=\<\#)(.*?)(?=\#\>)/";
preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
echo '<pre>',print_r($matches,true),'</pre>';

?>
```

now i am expecting a value array like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2134
            [1] => 213aca4
        )
)
```

But i am getting and output like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2134
            [1] => 213aca4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2134
            [1] => 213aca4
        )

)
```

can any one tell me why am i getting the second array and how can i get rid of that..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second array contains the sub-match, or matched group, because you're using a capture group.

Simply remove the parens in your regex:

```
$pattern = "/(?<=\<\#).*?(?=\#\>)/";
```

Also, you should be able to use this regex without some escapes:

```
$pattern = "/(?<=<#).*?(?=#>)/";
```